# HashMap overrides the nextvalue Java

Tags: java, hashmap

Lets say I have hashmap store  and it contains for example-(11,name1) (11,name2) and i call HashMap.get(11), it only shows name2 which means it overrides the first input for 11. How can i store both name1 and name2 with ID 11 using hashmap?I know i can use both HashMap and HashSet but i dont want to create every HashSet for HashMap. I just want to use hashSet only. how should I do this? I hope you can help me with it. Thank you.

```
public void insert(int ID, String key){
        int hashKey = Hash(key);
        System.out.println("Hash Key" + hashKey);
        int node = Find(ID,hashKey);

        storeR.put(node, key);
    }
```

Comment: A `Map` stores one value per key, therefore it will never contain `(11,name1)` **and** `(11,name2)` at the same time.

Comment: You can use a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` or a `Multimap<Integer, String>` which achieves the same thing.

Comment: make a map of `int` to `list-of-string` instead of jut `int` to `string`

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
HashMap<Integer, List<String>>
```

In `HashMap` you must put a value with every key. So of course, if you put the same key twice, the value will be override.

The solution is to hold a collection of values for every key.

in your code instead of:

```
storeR.put(node, key);
```

you should write:

```
List<String> nodeValues = storeR.get(node);
if (nodeValues == null) {
    nodeValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    storeR.put(node, nodeValues  );
}
nodeValues.add(key);
```

And you should also change `storeR` type to be `HashMap<Integer, List<String>>`

`MultiMap` is also a similar solution.

Comment: @baraky..sorry that I dont understand. storeR.put(node, key)..this is inside my function and key is String and node is integer. So should i change key into something?

Comment: Updated to node and key. Usually "key" is the map key but here you use it as a value. Perhaps you want to change the name for clarifying.

Comment: ..i try to do like urs but same node store the keys dat dont belong to also..like node 21, store all those name1,name2,name3 whereas these nodes belong to others..and my function will be called when the node is added..so its like once its called, the node and the key will be added at that time and next time it is called, it CAN be same node with different key..please look at my original post..I post my code there..sorry that i ask you so many questions.

Comment: No problem about the questions :) What are Hash and Find? and where you declare and initialize storeR?

Comment: private Map<Integer, List<String>> storeR..i declare that in the main also.Hash is trying to get the hash value from the String. say name1 is hashed to some int value. Find is finding the corresponding node...so I just want to store coressponding node and the String(key-in this case).

Comment: Check if node is the same for every key. If so, you need to check your "Find" method. The code will add values to the same list only if "node" is the same.

Comment: @baraky..i still dont find the way to change my code. Thanks for helping me out though..:)

Comment: @baraky..what i think is its nothing to do with find function. since find function return a value, i have to check a value is already inside the hashmap or not, if yes, den i need to store in that ..but I have no idea how to do that with hashmap.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably use [MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) from Apache Commons Collections.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to either have a `HashMap` where the value of each key is another collection (list or set) or concatenate the string values together (e.g. comma separated).

Alternatively you may be able to find a data collection that supports multiple values per key.

Answer (score 1):

To store multiple values for a single key, use a `HashMap` that contains a list as a value. `HashMap`'s implementation overrides values for existing keys.

```
HashMap<Integer,List<String>>
```

Also, you could use `MultiMap` from Apache Commons or, if you're just using `Integer` I can suggest you use an `array` directly:

```
List<String>[] yourList = new List<String>[initCapacity];
```

So you can access that list like this:

```
yourList[0].add("A New Value");
```

As a final note, you can use any collection you deem appropiate, even a HashSet if performance is important for you and you won't store duplicated values for a same index.